# Deleting descendants in Titan graph

Tags: java, graph-databases, titan

I want to remove a set of vertices together with all its descendants along given edge relations. In my case, the graph has some vertices whose type is *session*, and others whose type is *event*. There are arcs from events to sessions with a label *in_session*.

It seems there is no quick way to do this in one pass. Here is the code I used:

```
// First, select all event descendants of sessions with r < 700
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> t = g.V()
    .has("type", "session")
    .has("r", P.lt(700))
    .in("in_session");

// And remove those events
while (t.hasNext())
    t.next().remove();

// Then, using the first part of the query again, 
// select the same sessions as before
t = g.V().has("type", "session").has("r", P.lt(700));

// And delete them as well
while (t.hasNext())
    t.next().remove();
```

It seems very clunky to me. Moreover, if I wanted to remove lower level descendants I'd have to write more repeated steps (all the way down to the bottom, then remove, then back up one level, then remove, then back up one level again and so on...). Also I noticed there is no removeVertex method in TitanGraph.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use `sideEffect()`. Let's say I want to remove all "knows" vertices from the "marko" vertex in the TinkerPop [toy](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#toy-graphs) "modern" graph:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').outE()
==>e[9][1-created->3]
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').sideEffect(out('knows').drop()).drop()
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko')
gremlin> g.V(2)
gremlin> g.V(4)
gremlin> g.V(3)
==>v[3]
```

Note the use of `drop()` as opposed to iterating the traversal to call `remove()` on each element.

Comment: I used g.V().has("type", "session").has("r", P.lt(700)).sideEffect(in("in_session").drop()).drop() but no vertex was deleted. Also drop() isn't documented in thinkerpop javadoc.

Comment: first `drop()` is a method on the `GraphTraversal` class. see http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#drop-step - next you must iterate your traversal (the console does that for you) so if you are writing you code in java for instance you must terminate the traversal with `iterate()` - see http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration